# Uploading both data and files in one api call using Angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file, upload, form-data

I am writing an angular application which allows users to fill a form. This form accepts an image, another file, and other data such as label, description, etc. So far I have it uploading all the data as a dto but I intentionally chose not to include the files on the dto.

The original idea was to send the files to ImageKit so that I could avoid server side file management. Unfortunately, Imagekit is only letting me upload only images. I need a solution that allows me to upload both the image and the other file from the form together for consistency. If there are other free platforms with such a service, please let me know.

Meanwhile, I have resolved to upload the two files to my backend. This is the piece I need help with (Unless there is the alternative of a third party like Imagekit)

I have seen multiple suggestions on how to upload files but every example I see has a single file being appended to a `FormData`  object, which is then sent to the backend.

1. Is FormData only meant for files?
2. Can I add the file objects to my dto class or do I have to use FormData?
3. Can I do away with my dto and append all the members to the FormData object?
4. Do I have to do two api calls if the files have to go with FormData while the rest of the data goes in a dto?
5. Should I store the files in the db or the file system?
6. Is there a general/standard way to upload data that is associated with files?

I feel this is a common task i.e. saving user accounts which may have profile pictures

Comment: you can send FILE and other data using FormData.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-file-upload/

Else you can get the base64 string of uploading file using javascript File reader and use it with post method model.

Comment: When you say "post method model", are you referring to the dto model? I ask because even the FormData approach uses HttpPost

Comment: yes simple data model 
Get the base64 using below code
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}

var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file); // prints the base64 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 .Is FormData only meant for files?

No, you can use it for JSON, too. You need to convert it in a string like this way:

```
const sampleJson = { key: "Something Data", childs: [ {key: "Child Data"}, {key: "Child Data 2} ]};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", files);
formData.append("jsonData", JSON.stringify(sampleJson));
```

> 2. Can I add the file objects to my dto class or do I have to use FormData?

dto? So you work with NestJS? Normally files has nothing lost in databases. Instead you can set information like file name, file path.... to the table.

> 3. Can I do away with my dto and append all the members to the FormData object?

If i understand this correctly, yes with the way on point 1.

> 4. Do I have to do two api calls if the files have to go with FormData while the rest of the data goes in a dto?

No. Point 1.

> 5. Should I store the files in the db or the file system?

Never ever in db! Files have nothing lost in databases. It doesn't matter which DB it is. Use a file server, or the regular file system of the machine. Create a upload folder and set (with **Multer** as example - [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)) the static path and save files in this folder.

> 6. Is there a general/standard way to upload data that is associated with files?

Uploading is very easy you can see in point one. And on backend you can use **Multer** (see point 5). And with a express backend you can do the follow:

```
const uploadData = async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body.jsonData);

  for (let file of req.files) {
    console.log(file); // Here the file name, mimetype and so on...
    // The file itself is saved in the folder you have set with multer.
  }
...
```

Comment: When I said dto, I referred to a simple typescript interface with members that match my server side data class. Yeah, I'm using Kotlin

Comment: If you check the first comment on my question, @GouriSankar pointed that I can obtain the base64 string from the file and store that. Is that option included in your "Never db". I'm using postgres fyi

Comment: You "can" store base64 data. But if the file is very large I would convert it back to a file and store this on the filesystem.